# position in viewFlipper

Tags: android, viewflipper

How to find current view position in viewFlipper..

Suppose it is the last or the first child inside viewFlipper

```
  <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/imageFrames"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_dark" >
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"><RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"><RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"><RelativeLayout>
        </ViewFlipper>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild()`.